# Access 2013 Sum field column by ID number

Tags: ms-access

[My simple form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc0Wq.png)

Here is my simple purchase order form.
The form based on 2 tables. One named POMaster (data being POID and PODate) and the other one named Items(data being What you see plus a type called POIDno which is linked to the POID field to store items by POID)

How do I get Text10 to equal the sum of ItemTotal Column (By POID ofcourse) and if possible How do I get this value to store in a (hopefully) new data field in POMaster I would name POTotal?

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden total text box on the sub form and set your text box to the value of the hidden control.

You shouldn't store the value in the header as it can always be calculated.

However if you are storing it, you would have to determine a specific point in your process and ideally make sure no more updates can be made to the order lines, as that would mean having to re-calculate your stored value.

Comment: How do I get the text box to reference the total box?

Comment: Use the reference Me!Subform1.Form!ControlName 
Where Subform1 is your subform Name and ControlName is your hidden textbox. 

Make the textbox unhidden while getting it to work so you know it's doing the right thing.